# How to split a pandas series with multiple options?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a pandas dataframe with string column. What I am trying to do is separate the city name from the string.

Here is my MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = """\
2930 Beverly Glen Circle Los Angeles
435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles
12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City
9570 Wilshire Blvd. Beverly Hills
26025 Pacific Coast Hwy. Malibu""".split('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

cities = ['Los Angeles', 'Studio City', 'Beverly Hills','Malibu']

pat = '|'.join([r'(.*)\s({city})' for city in cities])
df = df[0].str.extract(pat,expand=True)
df
```

How to get the following output:

```
                                      0 addr                      city
0  2930 Beverly Glen Circle Los Angeles 2930 Beverly Glen Circle Los Angeles
1   435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 435 S. La Cienega Blvd.  Los Angeles
2       12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 12224 Ventura Blvd.      Studio City
3     9570 Wilshire Blvd. Beverly Hills 9570 Wilshire Blvd.      Beverly Hills
4       26025 Pacific Coast Hwy. Malibu 26025 Pacific Coast Hwy. Malibu
```

Comment: looks as if its working - what irks you?

Comment: It gives all NaN dataframe.

Comment: @astro123 you have used **raw string** while joining, use **f** for string formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the optional matches into one capture group:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """\
2930 Beverly Glen Circle Los Angeles
435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles
12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City
9570 Wilshire Blvd. Beverly Hills
26025 Pacific Coast Hwy. Malibu""".split('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

cities = ['Los Angeles', 'Studio City', 'Beverly Hills','Malibu']
c = '|'.join(cities)
pat = fr'(.*?)\s({c})'                     # fixed pattern with f and r
df = df[0].str.extract(pat,expand=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                          0              1
0  2930 Beverly Glen Circle    Los Angeles
1   435 S. La Cienega Blvd.    Los Angeles
2       12224 Ventura Blvd.    Studio City
3       9570 Wilshire Blvd.  Beverly Hills
4  26025 Pacific Coast Hwy.         Malibu
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know we can do `fr`. I only new either `f"hello"` or `r"hello"`. This solves my problem at hand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @astro it's short for french ;) ... rf"..." works as well

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
pat = '|'.join([rf'\s(?={city})' for city in cities])
df1 = df[0].str.split(pat, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'addr', 1: 'city'})
df = pd.concat([df[0], df1], axis=1)
```

Or, you can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pat = r'(?P<addr>.*)?\s' +  r'(?P<city>' + '|'.join(cities) + r')'
df = pd.concat([df[0], df[0].str.extract(pat, expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
                                      0                      addr           city
0  2930 Beverly Glen Circle Los Angeles  2930 Beverly Glen Circle    Los Angeles
1   435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles   435 S. La Cienega Blvd.    Los Angeles
2       12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City       12224 Ventura Blvd.    Studio City
3     9570 Wilshire Blvd. Beverly Hills       9570 Wilshire Blvd.  Beverly Hills
4       26025 Pacific Coast Hwy. Malibu  26025 Pacific Coast Hwy.         Malibu
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shubham. I have liked your question and appreciate it.